# H2 not creating table when using @Column(name="someName",columnDefinition = "FLOAT(10,7)")

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, h2

I'm using SpringBoot 1.5.14.RELEASE and com.h2database:h2. I have an entity that looks like this

```
//.... annotations here
public class SomeEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "some_columne_name", columnDefinition = "FLOAT(10,7)")
    private Double someColumnName;
}
```

The H2 is started with `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

But for some reason, H2 does not create the table because later in the code, when a select query run it throws `SQL Error:42102`, `Table not found`

if I start H2 without the `columnDefinition` in the entity then it creates the table successfully

How to create tables in H2 with `columnDefinition` in entities ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [H2 Data Types documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#double_type) the correct format is 
FLOAT(precisionInt) and not FLOAT(precisionInt, precisionInt). So all you have to do is to change column definition part and it will work.

e.g. `@Column(name = "some_columne_name", columnDefinition = "FLOAT(10)")`

As for what should be the value of precisionInt:

- Precision value for FLOAT type name should be from 0 to 24
- Precision value for DOUBLE type name should be from 25 to 53